# PHP: can't unset within an if in a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, unset

So I have an associative array, $data, pulled from a $_POST. Looping through with a foreach to reorder things as I want them for later in the program, like moving certain key->values into a "privacy" array as below, and I've come across a snag trying to unset some elements here:

```
public function create_profile($data, $files, $status) {
        $files = $files['files'];
        unset($files['files']);
        $privacy = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($key, 'privacy') !== false) {
                $privacy[$key] = $value;
                unset($data[$key]);
            }
            if (($key == 'filename') || ($key == 'fileyear')) {
                $files[$key] = array();
                for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data[$key]); $i++) {
                    if ($data[$key][$i] != '') {
                        $files[$key][$i] = $data[$key][$i];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $data[$key] = $value;
            }
            unset($data['filename']);
            unset($data['fileyear']);
        }

        $tokenized_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $data['display_name']);
        return($data);
}
```

The privacy array print_r's what it should, so I know it's finding the right elements, but it's not unsetting them, and I can't for the life of me think why. Which means it's surely something really dumb.

Comment: It works fine for me. You're missing a close brace, I added it in my code.

Comment: could you show full code (pasted lines works ok)?

Comment: That was just a code snippet, and didn't contain the rest of the foreach. It does now, as per my last edit, but it's the unset that's causing me difficulties.

Comment: Also, I know $files isn't declared in this code snippet, but that whole function is big, and everything else after that first unset is working as intended.

Comment: Why not, there's the whole function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that your `$data` array have something like this:
$data['privacy'] = 'foo';
$data['privacy-something'] = 'bar';
$data['test'] = 'foobar';

In this situation `strpos($key, 'privacy')` will not work correctly as `if` statement will return `false` for `0` value.

Also there was small brace problem at the end. So code that work perfectly for me looks like this:

```
$privacy = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'privacy') !== false) {
        $privacy[$key] = $value;
        unset($data[$key]);
    }
}
```

EDIT

Problem is here:

```
else {
    $data[$key] = $value;
}
```

You're setting unset value again. Why you need this?

Comment: Well, it's looping through $data finding keys that contain the string "privacy" and separating them out. There are a bunch, and strpos is finding them. I'm trying to unset the array keys where strpos returns true. The not-false didn't do it, though.

Comment: not-false helps find 'privacy' at beginning of key name. I know this is not a case.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear: the not-false didn't help with my original unset problem.